# How to change displayed text in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I installed `react-mailchimp-subscribe` and I want to change text button because my website is not written in English.
i putted this component into `div className="pokemon"`  to have access to him like `.pokemon > div > button` and could have change styles. Now I want to change text.
I try to acces to him by using

```
useEffect(() = > {
document.addEventListener("load", function(){
(".pokemon>div>button").innerHtml("Wyślij")
}); }, [])
```

but I guess in my function is too many errors that it actually work.

Comment: you can add class to that button.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the button label using the state. Please refer the below code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [buttonLabel, setButtonLabel ] = useState("I'm Button");

  useEffect(() => {
    setButtonLabel("Wyślij")
  }, [])

  return (
      <div className="pokemon">
      <div>
        <button> {buttonLabel}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-keller-d71kjq?file=/src/App.js:0-336) environment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using dom, you can use the below code.

You have some minor syntax mistake.

```
useEffect(() = > {
document.addEventListener("load", function(){
document.querySelector(".pokemon").querySelector("div").querySelector("button").innerHTML = "Wyślij";
}); }, [])
```